# Problems with laravel login function. I cannot retrieve data from db

Tags: sql, laravel

In my login, I want to redirect the user to the dashboard page where all posts of users that he follows, but my query doesn't retrieve the correct data. It returns an array without the information that I need.

I also receive an error when I try to login inside my application:

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number (SQL: select * from `posts` where `user_id` in (1, 1) order by `created_at` desc)
```

Here is my code,

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    if (!Auth::attempt($credentials))
        return redirect(route('public.login'))->with('error', 'Invalid credentials'); 

    $user = Auth::user();
    $followers_id = Follower::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();

    $post = Post::whereIn('user_id', $followers_id)->latest()->get();
  
    if ($user->hasRole('admin'))
        return redirect(route('admin.home'))->with('toast', 'Welcome, ' . $user->name . '!');

    $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
    return redirect(route('dashboard.home'))->with('toast', 'Welcome, ' . $user->name . '!');
}
```